# Is there a way to generate same Hmac hash output from PHP as done with nodejs?

Tags: php, node.js, utf-8, cryptography, hmac

Following is my **nodejs** function for creating HMAC hash -

```
function hash() {
    key = "hello";
    msg = "Hello";
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);
    hmac.update(msg, 'utf8');
    var digest = hmac.digest();
    console.log('---hash =======>' + digest);
    return digest;
}

function hmacHex(key, msg) {
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);
    hmac.update(msg, 'utf8');
    var digest = hmac.digest('hex');
    console.log('---hmacHex ====>' + digest);
    return digest;
}

var res = hash();
hmacHex("hello", res);
```

```
OUTPUT FROM hash() => }/�(K=�����('�Zt�h�\D�Z��@ywڦ�

OUTPUT FROM hmaxHex() => 692a18bd347476d28300e579794ba799cda80625191ef71783fce95692c2b6f9
```

Following is my **PHP** equivalent code for generating above mentioned output -

```
class Signature{

public function hash()
    {
        $key = "hello";
        $msg = "Hello";
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', utf8_encode($msg), $key, true);
        error_log('---hash ===>'.$hash);
        return $hash;
    }

public function hmacHex($msg)
    {
        $key = "hello";
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', utf8_encode($msg), $key, false);
        error_log('---hmacHex ===>' . $hash);
        return $hash;
    }
}

$obj = new Signature();

$res = $obj->hash();
$obj->hmacHex($res);
```

```
OUTPUT FROM hash() => }/?(K=?????('?Zt?h?\D?Z??@ywڦ?

OUTPUT FROM hmacHex => d920859abc579a070f2f8177e71d8431955784c8ed1d596b3364871ba35b5951
```

From the outputs, it is clear that in nodejs I am getting replacement characters whereas in PHP it appears as a question mark.

I am trying to generate exactly the same output from my PHP code so that when the outputs are rehashed it should be the same.

Comment: Are you sure that the `?` characters are not just the way it is displayed?  Have you checked the binary for these strings to see if they are the same.

Comment: Yes, even I thought it just the way it is displayed, so I rehashed the outputs but the hash generated was completely different.

Comment: When the data is printed, a charset encoding is implicitly used (probably UTF8), corrupting the original data. For comparison, hex encoding would be useful, i.e. `digest.toString('hex')` in the NodeJS code and `bin2hex($hash)` in the PHP code. Both results are identical.

Comment: Yes, the hex output is the same if I use the above-generated outputs and hash them again using hmacHex the output generated is completely different.

Comment: The UTF8 encoding of already binary data in `hmacHex()` is wrong. In the PHP code it corrupts the data, in the NodeJS code it is ignored. Remove in the PHP Code in `hmacHex()` the `utf8_encode()`-call.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked after removing utf8_encode from hmacHex()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll update my answer to reflect your code changes. Thanks to @Topaco for resolving the issue.

**php**

```
class Signature {

    public function hash()
    {
        $key = "hello";
        $msg = "Hello";
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $msg, $key, true);
        error_log('---hash ===>'.$hash);
        return $hash;
    }

    public function hmacHex($msg)
    {
        $key = "hello";
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $msg, $key, false);
        error_log('---hmacHex ===>' . $hash);
        return $hash;
    }
}

$obj = new Signature();

$res = $obj->hash();
$obj->hmacHex($res);
```

**node**

```
class Signature {

    public function hash()
    {
        $key = "hello";
        $msg = "Hello";
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $msg, $key, true);
        error_log('---hash ===>'.$hash);
        return $hash;
    }

    public function hmacHex($msg)
    {
        $key = "hello";
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $msg, $key, false);
        error_log('---hmacHex ===>' . $hash);
        return $hash;
    }
}

$obj = new Signature();

$res = $obj->hash();
$obj->hmacHex($res);
```

php output:

```
---hash ===>}/(K=('Zth\DZ@ywڦ
---hmacHex ===>692a18bd347476d28300e579794ba799cda80625191ef71783fce95692c2b6f9
```

Node.js output:

```
---hash =======>}/�(K=�����('�Zt�h�\D�Z��@ywڦ�
---hmacHex ====>692a18bd347476d28300e579794ba799cda80625191ef71783fce95692c2b6f9
```

Comment: The base64 output as you mentioned is the same, but if I rehash the outputs generated from my code using hmacHex I am getting completely different values in PHP & nodejs

Comment: Could you update the question with this code? We can then reproduce what you're seeing, and hopefully find a solution!

Comment: I have updated my code. After generating the initial hash I am rehashing the response with Hmac hex.

Answer (score 1):

your $key php side must be utf8_encode because on the node side `crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);`

the key here is utf8 encoded by `crypto.createHmac`.